# Why Do Sausages Always Split Lengthwise?

Tags: everyday-life, fracture

Sausages universally split parallel to the length of the sausage. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: The video explains it fairly well. There is greater tension release when the split propagates along the length.

Comment: Being cooked too long probably.

Comment: First use of the fracture tag.

Comment: In the image in the question, two of the sausages appear to split in a spiral about the length.

Comment: @einnocent a sausage casing is not a uniform tube. I think that there must be some natural fault there, which has a spiral shape because either a) the sausage was produced straight, but animal guts have a spiral like structure, or b) guts have a lengthwise structure and the sausage production process involves twisting during filling. My cooking and biology knowledge let me think there is about 80% chance of b) being the correct explanation of the spiral, 10% a), 10% something I forgot to think of.

Comment: You can see how sausages are wrapped here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fW-VMGxeRew&t=53 Note how the linker spins the casing, which may contribute to helical stress.

Comment: Is this picture making anybody else hungry?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This behaviour is well explained by [Barlow's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barlow%27s_formula), even though the English Wikipedia article is incomplete in this context. The [German version](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kesselformel), on the other hand, gives the full picture (which I will quote in the following).

[image: Stresses in a thin-walled cylinder; Source: Wikimedia commons]

The walls of a pipe (or a similar cylindric container, say, a sausage) experience two types of stresses: Tangential ($\sigma_{\rm{t}}$) and axial ($\sigma_{\rm{a}}$). For given pressure $p$, diameter $d$ and wall-thickness $s$, the individual stresses can approximately be calculated from
$$\sigma_{\rm{t}} = \frac { p \cdot d } { 2 \cdot s }$$
and
$$\sigma_{\rm{a}} = \frac { p \cdot d } { 4 \cdot s }.$$
Here, you can directly see that the tangential stress will always be larger, which is why it is likely that cracks in the container/sausage will first form in this direction. In fact, this is why the first formula is often stated on its own, just as it is the case in the English Wikipedia article.

Fun fact: The sausage example is used by many German students as a mnemonic helping to remember which of the stresses is larger. As a result, the formulas are often called "Bockwurstformeln" (sausage formulas).

Edit: In response to the comments below, I will try to summarize some details about the above formulas

- The formulas do not directly indicate how and where the container will split. Assuming that the tensile strength is identical in all directions, we can see that there will be a greater release of tension when the crack propagates length-wise (See the video posted by JoeHobbit and the comment by LDC3)
- A real sausage will of course have various imperfections, which is why the crack path will not be straight in practice

Comment: Cool ,you learn something new every day :-) A minor clarification, the cracks form normal to the tangential stress so that they reduce the tangential stress as they widen.

Comment: of course stating that the guaranteed higher tangential stress causes a break to (almost) always be lengthwise assumes that tensile strength is identical in all directions.

Comment: @jwenting: Indeed, there are quite a couple of assumptions behind these formulas...

Comment: @bigge well, the formulae are not dependent on the tensile strength of the material, only on the dimensions of the tube. Tensile strength of course does influence whether the tube can withstand a stress on it, but not the stress itself.

Comment: This assumes an "ideal sausage" (infinitely long, no discontinuities), does it not?  In a real sausage, uneven stress lines would overwhelm the ideal formula's effect.  In this respect, @BigHomie's answer is more correct, in that stress concentrations due to the weak ends would be the deciding factor in stress failure.

Comment: @SethBattin ideal sausage <3

Comment: The cylinder is not assumed infinite. Fluid pressure always acts orthogonally to a surface. A cylinder's side is parallel to its axis so doesn't contribute to axial stress. Only the ends can do that, and an infinite cylinder doesn't have ends.

Comment: You're perfectly right, I missed that when incorporating the edits...

Comment: "In dieser Form ist die Kesselformel auch als Bockwurst-Formel bekannt" (in wiki.de talking about the forms you quote) - why is this a mnemonic? Sounds like a fun fact, but as far as I can see you'd simply have to recall the two formulas by rote. Or is it the near universal fact that a sausage splits along its length the mnemonic, i.e. you can recall that sausages split this way easily, so you know that $\sigma_t$ has to be the bigger of the two?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance: The latter is true; I'll try clarify that in my answer.

Answer (score 16):

I'll have to take a page from my EE background and say it's because of the path of least resistance. If you look at the end of a sausage, there is already tension along that plane, in multiple locations:

[image]

A *chain* is only as strong as its weakest link (see what I did there? :) ), so it's natural for a hot dog/sausage to split along a path that's already strained.

Comment: Very _punny_. :)

Comment: You guys are going to make me split at the seams with laughter.

Comment: That's the wurst joke that I've heard all day.

Comment: This appears to be a link-only answer.

Comment: @JasonC nice one, I should have brat my A game.